# Adaboost: model depth lager than number of predictors

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting, adaboost

I noticed that I can train models in the R package gbm that have interaction depth larger than the total number of predictors used to train the model. How is it possible that I can train a model of depth 8 using only 3 predictors? Shouldn’t I be able only train it up to depth 3? What is the algorithm doing differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each node in the design tree splits the predictors space to two parts. So, a new split for an already used variable sometimes can provide performance improvement.

Consider for example, a function $f(x) = \begin{cases} 
0, x_1 < 2, \\ 
1, x_2 < 0, x_1 \geq 2, \\
2, x_2 \geq 0, 2 \leq x_1 \leq 3, \\
3, x_2 \geq 0, x_1 > 3. \end{cases}$

Such function for perfect classification requires two nodes with $x_1$.
[image]